# Google play store rejected my app

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

Me and My collaborator(iOs developer), developed an application. I developed the Android version and He developed the iOS version. So, we used the same content and images. He published successfully his iOs version, but Google play store rejected my Android version - because I used the same icons of the iOs version.

At First they sent me an email saying that:

> Thanks for submitting nameOfMyApp ( to
>   Google Play.
>
> I reviewed your app and had to reject it because of an unauthorized
>   use of copyrighted content.

And they sent me a second email after suspending my application saying:

> After review, **nameOfMyApp**, has been
>   suspended and removed from Google Play as a policy strike because it
>   violates the impersonation policy. Your app is identical to an
>   existing app on the Play Store.

Really, it is a big problem for me.
Who Knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did they tell you the name of the app you were supposedly copying? Try filing an appeal => https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981?hl=en

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Write them and tell them that you're legitimately using those icons, because you're in a partnership with the iOS app developer. Unless he's also not using copyrighted material (and Apple failed to spot that out).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the Google Play Store support site. Contact them directly via the link provided in the email to discuss problems with your specific account or application. We cannot assist with such issues, because we are not Google Play Store support. This is clearly covered in [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/62576) at [meta].

Comment: Often the Google Play do that, but, they have inside politics about copyrights
you may change your logo or content, if you want to publish it.

Comment: @Ken white : why it is off topic? I'm looking for people who faced the same problem and asking them what they do ? (I asked google play support and I'm still waiting a response  ). For me,  any response or suggestion would help me . And this problem can be faced by anyone. And if I resolve it , I will tell what I have done.

Comment: I provided the link to Meta that explained why. Did you read it? It's off topic because we are not Google Play Store support, we don't have information about your app or your account, and we can do nothing about the issue. **Address it with Google Play Store support, via the contact information that was provided to you.**  The site that is appropriate will have *google.com* in the URL. This site does not.

Comment: @KenWhite I am facing the same issue but they don't mention the real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue once, and after exchanging some mails with proof(official signed and stamped documents) that my app's content was not copied, thus no 'impersonation' took place. I think this is your only chance, to get in touch with the support and explain the issue, backing it up with documents and the proof you can gather.

Comment: Yes , I solved my problem by exchanging mail with google support team and sending them documents and proofs that explain our right to use the content

Comment: Glad to hear that @Nmna!

Answer (score 2):

Read [**`unauthorized use of copyrighted content`**](https://play.google.com/about/ip-impersonation/ip/unauthorized-copyright/)

Please be careful when using copyrighted content to demonstrate the functionality of your app. In general, the safest approach is to create something that’s original.

- Check App Name
- Check App LOGO/ICON

> We don’t allow apps that use another app or entity’s brand, title,
>   logo, or name in a manner that may result in misleading users. Don’t
>   try to imply an endorsement or relationship with another entity where
>   none exists. Impersonation can occur even if there isn’t an intent to
>   deceive, so please be careful when referencing any brands that do not
>   belong to you. This applies even if that brand doesn’t yet have a
>   presence on Google Play.

Read [**`Impersonation and Intellectual Property`**](https://play.google.com/about/ip-impersonation/).

Comment: Even facebook , tweeter ...have  two version Android and iOS version . Why we could not have the same app name and logo in google play  and iOS play store  ?

Comment: @Nmna No no, I strongly believe there are something sloppy mistake coming. `Your app is identical to an existing app on the Play Store.` check your app name and icon same as another app .

Comment: @Nmna You should contact with google team.

Comment: Yeah I have contacted them and I m waiting their response.

Comment: @Nmna Solved this yet?

Comment: My application has not been  published yet . But google support  send me this : **We’ve accepted your appeal and your app has been reinstated. For the app to appear on Google Play, you’ll need to sign in to your Play Console and click "Submit update."**

 I did the changement and I'm still waiting them to confirm the publication of my app.

Comment: @Nmna indeed.wait.

Comment: Yes it published finally :D Thank @Intellij for asking .  I already give you a plus for the advice ^^

Comment: @Nmna Move ahead.